# Make similar methods generic sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've been using the SQLite helper class [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/#/) to add and retrieve data from my application to a database.

I've ended up with lots of similar methods where the only difference is the SQLite tablename and the casting from the dataobject to table and vice versa.

Is there a neater way of doing this to make these methods more generic for any number of fields and data types?

(The real header names have been changed!)

**Example of 2 insert methods:**

```
private void AddProgresstoDb(DataObj.Progress progress)
{
    //INSERT SQlite
    SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteDatabase();

        Dictionary<String, String> data = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        data.Add("fieldAA", progress.fieldAA.ToString());
        data.Add("fieldAB", progress.fieldAB);
        data.Add("fieldAC", progress.fieldAC.ToString());
        data.Add("fieldAD", progress.fieldAD.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        data.Add("fieldAE", progress.fieldAE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        data.Add("fieldAF", progress.fieldAF);
        data.Add("fieldAG", progress.fieldAG.ToString());
        data.Add("fieldAH", progress.fieldAH.ToString());
        data.Add("fieldAI", progress.fieldAI.ToString());
        try
        {
            db.Insert("tableProgress", data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle error
        }

}


private void AddResulttoDb(DataObj.Result result)
{
    //INSERT SQlite
    SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteDatabase();

        Dictionary<String, String> data = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        data.Add("fieldBA", result.fieldBA.ToString());
        data.Add("fieldBB", result.fieldBB);
        data.Add("fieldBC", result.fieldBC.ToString());
        data.Add("fieldBD", result.fieldBD.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        data.Add("fieldBF", result.fieldBF);
        try
        {
            db.Insert("tableResult", data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle error
        }

}
```

**Example of 1 GetDataTable method:**

```
private ObservableCollection<DataObj.Progress> GetProgressfromDb()
{
    var progress = new ObservableCollection<DataObj.Progress>();
    //QUERY SQlite
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteDatabase();
        DataTable prog;
        String query = "select * from tableProgress;";
        prog = db.GetDataTable(query);

        foreach (DataRow r in prog.Rows)
        {
            progress.Add(new DataObj.Progress()
            {
                fieldAA =  Convert.ToInt32(r["fieldAA"]),
                fieldAB = r["fieldAB"].ToString(),
                fieldAC = (DateTime)r["fieldAC"],
                fieldAD = (DateTime)r["fieldAD"],
                fieldAE = r["fieldAE"].ToString(),
                fieldAF = (decimal)r["fieldAF"],
                fieldAG = (decimal)r["fieldAG"],
                fieldAH = r["fieldAH"].ToString(),
                fieldAI = (decimal)r["fieldAI"]
            });
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle error
    }

    return progress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to work with an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) framework such as Entity Framework, instead of writing the SQL by yourself.

See an example [here](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.fr/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html).